# azure ioteage device module fails to communicate with rabbitmq module on actual device

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, azure-devops, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

We are currently attempting to create a device with 2 modules:

- an Asp .net core website
- a RabbitMQ module

But the website fails to discover the RabbitMQ ("None of the specified endpoints were reachable").

We have tried changing the network the modules belong to to either host or our specific network to no avail.

We are using an arm32v7 device running debian.

our deployment json: 
https://api.myjson.com/bins/11n7r8

Comment: By default, IoT Edge creates its own bridge network ("azure-iot-edge"), and connects each deployed module to it. In that configuration, module containers should be able to communicate with each other over any port, without exposing or binding/publishing anything. Each module can be addressed by its IP address or the module name in the deployment JSON, since IoT Edge automatically sets up the module name as the hostname. What happens if you deploy your two modules to the edge *without* any "createOptions"? Also, what mechanism is your web server using to discover the RabbitMQ server?

Comment: we are using the c# client (https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client)

Comment: What happens if you deploy your two modules to the edge without any "createOptions"?